# MLP classifier Gridsearch CV parameters to tune?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameter-tuning, mlp, grid-search

I'm looking to tune the parameters for sklearn's MLP classifier but don't know which to tune/how many  options to give them? Example is learning rate. should i give it[.0001,.001,.01,.1,.2,.3]? or is that too many, too little etc.. i have no basis to know what is a good range for any of the parameters. Processing power is limited so i can't just test the full range. If anyone has a general guide of which are the most important to tune and a general range that would help me a lot moving forward. Thanks!

Comment: this is the art of machine learning, all these parameters have no magic values, it is a systemartic trial and error process in the end

Answer (score 0):

Usually learning rate would be between 0.0 to 1.0 , please go ahead by specifying values in those range.
[This thread would be definitely helpful for your further research and reference](https://machinelearningmastery.com/understand-the-dynamics-of-learning-rate-on-deep-learning-neural-networks/#:%7E:text=The%20amount%20that%20the%20weights,range%20between%200.0%20and%201.0.)

Thanks,
Durga

Comment: That's great for learning rate thank you, for the other parameters such as alpha, max_itr, and hidden layer size do you have any suggestions?